# SPD - Inline Editing

Tags: data-view-web-part, custom-form, sharepoint-designer

How do I customize the edit template to look different than the default template?  For example, I'd like to only display a few columns of information but when the edit link is clicked on for the DVWP, more columns show up and data is allowed to be typed.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but would love to know/how to do it...

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Isn't the XSLT for the edit templates available to edit within the markup?

Comment: I think you are right and I also think I've found it... I switched to the edit template and clicked on a drop-down field.  It highlighted the code, so now I *think* I know where to edit my stuff at.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the active template using the Smart Menu in SharePoint Designer to "Edit", and you'll be able to select your columns.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer, create a copy of the Edit form. You can then modify the form with some jQuery to hide certain rows. You can then change the mappings for the list to point to your new edit form. You can edit the edit form directly, but that's not generally a best practice. You should always keep those OOTB files unchanged so you have them to reference or restore.

Comment: When Matt said "inline" I thought he meant DataFormWebPart, as opposed to alternate EditForm.aspx?

Matt - can you clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to use the inline editing feature for the DVWP.  I'm not sure if I follow you.  When I click on the edit link next to the particular row, it changes the labels to input boxes of the correct type.  I'm trying to make that dynamic by showing more fields within the edit mode.  I like jQuery but it's still Japanese at this point...  I'm such a noob when it comes to that :)

Comment: This can be done by editing the markup, but I'm not 100% if it can be done via the SharePoint Designer GUI, will have a play.

Comment: Tru... I don't think it can be done via the GUI.  Anyone know if it can be?

Comment: This stuff is awesome looking: <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Meeting_x0020_Type" ItemId="{@ID}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Meeting_x0020_Type')}" />